# How to filter based on the URL of an image in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a filter view in Google Sheets that will only show certain rows of the spreadsheet based on the last few characters of the URL of the images that are inserted in every row. For example, most rows have an image that is simply named "image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", etc, but every once in a while there'll be a row where the image is named "image63_s.png", "image176_s.png", "image271_s.png", etc. What I'd like to do is create a filter view that will only show rows where the name of the image in the URL ends with "_s".

EDIT: The images are inserted into the sheet with the formula `=IMAGE("https://www.example.com/site/image1.png")`, so I don't think regex can work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, ".*_s.png$")
```

---

### update:

```
=REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT(A1), ".*_s.png.*")
```

or as suggested have a hidden helper column of urls

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't seem to work. From what I could find from searching before I asked this question, regex only works on text, not images. The images are inserted into the sheet with the formula `=IMAGE("https://www.example.com/site/image1.png")`

Comment: @Gameskiller01 what about if you have the URL in a different cell and you regex that one and in the other one you have the image. e.g. `=IMAGE(A1)` and if it's because of the visuals, hide the column where the URL is

Comment: @DavidSalomon That's a great idea, thanks! If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Gameskiller01 answer updated